# Setting up breakpoints at all functions in a file in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, debugging, gdb, qt-creator

I'm trying to read the source code of a project. There are many functions I would like to inspect. Right clicking and inserting breakpoints at all the functions takes lot of time.

It is possible to insert break points at all functions in a file using gdb command line. I was wondering if it can be done inside Qt Creator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to give commands directly to GDB in Qt Creator. See [Directly Interacting with Native Debuggers](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debug-mode.html#directly-interacting-with-native-debuggers).

And yes, as you can read [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html#Set-Breaks) it is possible set breakpoints on every function in a given file. What you need is the **rbreak** command:

> rbreak file:regex
>   If rbreak is called with a filename qualification, it limits the search for functions matching the given regular expression to the
>   specified file. This can be used, for example, to set breakpoints on
>   every function in a given file:
>
> ```
>           (gdb) rbreak file.c:.
> ```
>
> The colon separating the filename qualifier from the regex may optionally be surrounded by spaces.

Comment: finding debugger log took me some time :)